# Left Join and Group By with possible empty row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by, left-join

I have these tables

```
`Sales.Branch`
-Id
-Name
        ==Rows in Sales.Branches==
         - Al Ain
         - Chamber
         - Hamdan
         - Mina
         - Marina
         - EMTI

`Sales.Transaction`

- Id
- Date
- BranchId

`Sales.TransactionItem`
- Id
- TransactionId
- Pages
- Rate
```

I want to get a report of their `total Sales`, `TotalPages` and `No. OF Transaction` on specific `Start` and `End` `Dates`.

I've tried this query but it only returns Branches that have transactions on specified dates.

```
select
    b.Name as BranchName,
    COUNT(t.Id) as Transactions,
    SUM(ti.Pages * ti.Rate) as TotalSales,
    SUM(ti.Pages) as Pages

    from 
        Sales.[Transaction] t
            left join Sales.TransactionItem ti
            on ti.TransactionId = t.Id
            left join Sales.Branch b on b.Id = t.BranchId
    where t.Date >= '2016-01-01'
AND t.Date <= '2016-02-01'
    group by b.Name
    order by b.Name ASC
```

[image]

Since the `EMTI` Branch doesn't have Transaction on `2016-01-01` until `2016-02-01` it is not included in the result.

What I want is include **ALL** branches even they dont have Transaction, and display `0` on `TotalSales, TotalPAges, Transactions` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Branch as the main table and put condition on time to join:

```
select
    b.Name as BranchName,
    COUNT(t.Id) as Transactions,
    SUM(ISNULL(ti.Pages, 0) * ISNULL(ti.Rate, 0)) as TotalSales,
    SUM(ISNULL(ti.Pages, 0)) as Pages
from 
    Sales.Branch b
        left join Sales.[Transaction] t 
            on b.Id = t.BranchId 
            and t.Date >= '2016-01-01'
            AND t.Date <= '2016-02-01'
        left join Sales.TransactionItem ti
            on ti.TransactionId = t.Id
group by b.Name
order by b.Name ASC
```

Comment: thank you. This works! Please accept the edit for some finishing touches

Answer (score 0):

Please select data from branch table as a parent table and check isnull

```
select
b.Name as BranchName,
COUNT(ISNULL(t.Id,0)) as Transactions,
SUM(ISNULL(ti.Pages,0) * ISNULL(ti.Rate,0)) as TotalSales,
SUM(ISNULL(ti.Pages,0)) as Pages

from Sales.Branch b 
    left join  Sales.[Transaction] t on b.Id = t.BranchId
        left join Sales.TransactionItem ti
        on ti.TransactionId = t.Id
where t.Date >= '2016-01-01'
AND t.Date <= '2016-02-01'
group by b.Name
order by b.Name ASC
```